# JIRA automation treats active users as inactive for issue assignment

Tags: jira, jira-automation

I am loading the list of members of a group, then creating one issue for each of them through automation.

[image]

Next step is creating the variable

[image]

I then loop through it with

[image]

And within the branches I create the task using

[image]

And the result is below:

[image]

with the audit log as below

[image]

As you can see it has worked as expected, except for the assignments where it has only been successful for one user (cf inactive user warning in the audit log).

I have checked the result payload in the first step and all users are marked as active. I also know for a fact that the accounts are all actively used daily.

Any idea why this is happening or how I should change the way I process the list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a variable and then loop over the split of the variable, just use the list `{{webResponse.body.values.accountId}}` directly in the advanced branch and skip the variable creation step.